# How can I move to a pointer position directly without using the ++ operator?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, pointer-arithmetic

I'm working with a pointer to a structure. I want to know if is possible move directly to a specific position without use `++` operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

struct dummy{
    int id;
    char buffer[10];
};

typedef struct dummy dummy_struct;

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    dummy_struct *ds = malloc(sizeof(dummy_struct)*ARRAY_SIZE);
    dummy_struct *iterator = ds;

    for(i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
        iterator->id = i;
        sprintf(iterator->buffer,"%d",i);
        iterator++;
    }

    iterator = ds;

    for(i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("%d:%s:%p\n",iterator->id,iterator->buffer,iterator);
        iterator++;
    }

    // I want to access directly to 5th position
    iterator = ds + (sizeof(dummy_struct)*5);
    printf("5th position %d:%s:%p\n",iterator->id,iterator->buffer,iterator);

    return 0;
}
```

This statement

```
iterator = ds + (sizeof(dummy_struct)*5);
```

is not working. I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: For any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i` the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. Pointer arithmetic is just a fancy way of indexing an "array".

Comment: ... or rather, `p[i]` is just fancy syntactic sugar for `*(p + i)` (as it is).

Comment: Simply write `iterator = &ds[5];`.

Comment: `x++` is essentially `x=x+1`, not `x=x+sizeof(something)`.

Comment: @Dukeling `x++` is indeed the same as `x = x + 1`, but it does have the effect though of advancing `x` by `sizeof *x` bytes if you examine the raw value of the pointer.

Comment: @Alnitak That is true, but it is equally true than `x += n` will advance x by `n* sizeof *x` bytes if you examine the raw value of the pointer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, pointer arithmetic honors the data type!!

```
iterator = ds + 5;
```

will get the job done.

To elaborate, the above expression will produce a pointer by moving it 5 times, multiplied by the size of type for `ds`, in bytes. That's the same as `&(ds[5])`.

For sake of completeness, explaining why `iterator = ds + (sizeof(dummy_struct)*5);` is wrong, is, here, you're essentially trying to move the pointer to an element with index as `(sizeof(dummy_struct)*5` which is, well out of bounds. Note please, this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)!! <sup>note below</sup>

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6/P8

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
>   result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression `P` points to
>   the `i`-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and
>   `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist. [....]

and then, regarding the undefined behavior mentioned above,

> [....] If both the pointer
>   operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
>   element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
>   shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated.

---

That being said, the `printf()` statement is also erroneous. You have two conversion specifiers, but supplied three arguments. It's not *harmful*, but useless/meaningless.

Related, from chapter §7.21.6.1/P2,

> [...] If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
>   evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. [...]

Based on this case, you can directly use

```
printf("5th position %d:%s:\n",ds[5].id,ds[5].buffer);
```

Comment: In order to do my code works I modified with this line: `iterator = ds + 5`. Thanks!!!

Comment: @RubénPozo Ah, right, let me also make that correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba And I get a view  from Mariana Trench to top of Mount Everest.

Comment: I find that when answering what is clearly a basic question, merely quoting the standard isn't helping many people. Most people at this level of question need an explanation in plain English as well.

Comment: @Joe If you feel it's not helping, I encourage you to downvote. However, FYI, I just added a couple of line of explanation, if that helps.

Comment: @Joe, that's why a selection of answers is always useful on SO. Sourav Ghosh likes to use standard references which gives his answers a reference quality. I tend not to, mainly because I'm essentially a charlatan who doesn't know the standard as well as I ought. Remember that SO is a Q & A site, not a forum targetting helping individual users (although that does drop out as a corollary).

Answer (score 8):

The behaviour of

```
iterator = ds + (sizeof(dummy_struct) * 5);
```

is *undefined* if you set a pointer beyond one past the final element of the array. You are actually setting `iterator` to further elements in the array than you think, by a factor of `sizeof(dummy_struct)`! Don't do that.

The language allows you to use the notation `iterator = ds + 5;`. This idiomatic *pointer arithmetic* adds `5` lots of `sizeof(dummy_struct)` to the address `iterator`. In other words the compiler does the `sizeof` adjustment for you. That's one reason why pointer arithmetic is so powerful.

Finally note that `*(ds + 5)` is equivalent to `ds[5]`. I find the latter affords more clarity when working with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are trying to make the `iterator` pointer pointing to `5th` element of `ds` array. But this statement will give you wrong result:

```
iterator = ds + (sizeof(dummy_struct)*5);
```

The result of `sizeof(dummy_struct)*5` will result in the total size of all the elements of structure `dummy_struct` multiplied by 5, which will get added to the address referenced by `ds` and assigned to `iterator`. So, the `iterator` may point to a memory location which your program does not own. You need to do:

```
iterator = ds + 5;
```

Or you can also do:

```
iterator = &ds[5];
```

Comment: &ds[4] is equivalent to ds + 4. Note also that the compiler is not allowed to *dereference* `ds + 4` in the former expression